Will my TV mount secured to brick with masonry screws hold a larger TV?
Will Tapcons hold 75 in. TV in Brick Fireplace?
A year ago, I installed a MantelMount M700 (20-30 pounds) with a 50-inch TV (about 30 pounds) on my painted brick fireplace and have had no issues. I used 4 Tapcon screws to secure the mount (used a hammer drill with the correct pre-drilled hole size; screws are placed in the brick itself, not the mortar). I didn’t use epoxy or anything, and the brick seemed solid—it took significant effort to drill with the hammer drill. I'm unsure of the type of brick that I have, but again, it seems strong and it did not seem like there was chipping or anything when drilling into it. I may be able to get a picture of the unpainted brick from the outside of the house if that helps.
Now, I’ve upgraded to a 75-inch TV (about 70 pounds), and I’m worried about the screws holding up. I don’t see any signs of the screws pulling out, but everything I’ve read says the weight capacity depends on the quality and softness of the brick. I’m also concerned that repeated use of the MantelMount (swinging the TV up and down) might wear on the brick and loosen the screws over time.
I cannot remember the exact size of the Tapcons used, but I think they were the 1/4 inch diameter. They are evenly distributed in a square on the mount. The TV typically goes up and down once every day or two, nothing major, but still when its down and further away from the wall in the MantelMount I would imagine that adds some stress to the screws.
Is there any way I can reinforce this setup to handle the additional weight and prevent wear over time? Should I be worried about the screws pulling out, or is this setup fine?

Seems like you'd tell us what length and diameter screws you used. You're asking for a load assessment, but you left out what might be the most critical information of all. Please take the [tour].

Give it a yank and see.
The problem with masonry screws is that they either hold really well or they don't hold at all. There's not much middle ground. Only a load test will tell the story.
Also, if you remove the screws you destroy the ability for them to grip. By removing them you tear out the threads that were cut into the brick. Therefore, if you do remove them, you'll need to use different holes, or plastic plug anchors, or epoxy, when you reinstall them. (Don't reuse the same screws. Their threads get rounded off too.)
If it was mine I'd either add a couple more screws (drill new holes in the mount if you have to) or do a load test ape-style. Or just read a book. The world could use more of that anyway.
